# Which wsdl attribute should I apply to the platform event file for publish behavior

Tags: salesforcedx, platform-event

I have changed a platform event's publish behavior to be publish after commit. Since we are using salesforce dx to deploy the changes, we need to capture the change in the related file.

Obviously sfdx force:source:pull doesn't track the change. I searched through the enterprise wsdl file but still haven't got a clue on which attribute should I apply to the platform event file. Any suggestions?

Comment: What API version is your SFDX project using? I'm pretty sure this works on API 46.

Comment: @DavidReed It think it is 45. Which attribute is that? Can I manually add it or do I need to upgrade to 46?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Publish On Commit was introduced in [Summer '19](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_platfom_event_post_commit.htm), API version 46.0.

The relevant XML source attribute is `publishBehavior`, but it won't work at all unless you're operating on API 46. You'll need to update the API version in your `sfdx-project.json`.